# Disable a compiler warning which is not in the rule set

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

My C# application uses the Code Analysis rule set `Microsoft Managed Recommended Rules`. I'm using some obsolete classes so I get the warning CS0618. (I cannot replace the obsolete classes because it's defined in a 3rd party API, so I have to use it)

I wanted to disable this warning by editing the default rule set and saving it under a new name, but the CS0618 rule is not part of this rule set.

So I have two questions:

- Why does the compiler check against CS0618 although it's not part of the selected rule set?
- How can I disable the warning per project/per solution and not in each single place?

For those who are curious why I cannot simply fix the compiler warning:
see [Refactoring XmlSchemaCollection, XmlValidatingReader and ValidationType.XDR to get rid of compiler warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723218/refactoring-xmlschemacollection-xmlvalidatingreader-and-validationtype-xdr-to-g)

Comment: Code Analysis rules/warnings start with `CA`. C Sharp warnings/errors start with `CS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CS0168 isn't part of Code Analysis - it's a simple C# compiler warning. That's got nothing to do with any later code analysis.

To disable it in project properties, go into the project properties, the Build tab, Errors and Warnings section, Suppress Warnings, and specify 0168 (not CS0168).

Comment: Problem 1) I need to use XML based on XDR schemas. I have already tried to apply every suggestion offered by Visual Studio to replace it by something else, but I never managed to get out of the obsolete mode. I think that's because XDR is obsolete in general, no matter which class you use. If you know a solution to use XDR without obsolete classes, I'm glad to ask a new question - and even offer a bounty on that.

Comment: @ThomasW.: Not knowing anything about XDR, do you mean that this is generated code and you don't control the generation part? (It's not clear which "obsolete class" is causing the problem, or why you need to recompile it.)

Comment: XDR is Microsoft XML-Data Reduced. The obsolete classes to work with XDR are System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaCollection, System.Xml.XmlValidatingReader and the enum System.Xml.ValidationType.XDR

Comment: @ThomasW.: But you don't need to compile those classes, do you? What *source code* is causing the warning, and why can't you fix it?

Comment: I have posted my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723218/refactoring-xmlschemacollection-xmlvalidatingreader-and-validationtype-xdr-to-g

Comment: @ThomasW.: Doh - it turns out I'd searched for the wrong warning. I thought it was about an unused variable. Right, in this case just disabling it for the project - or using `#pragma warning disable` for a single source file - is fine. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @ThomasW.: Ah, I now see why I did so. I was reading the first version of your question, which had a typo for one of the warnings. I'd unfortunately picked that one to search for instead of the other :(

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mistyped the number even twice. Anyway, I'm excited about any answers for the new question.

Comment: @ThomasW.: Unfortunately I don't have any suggestions there :(

Comment: @JonSkeet is it possible - or good practice - to use the `SuppressWarning` attribute, here?

Comment: @Thomas: For a C# compiler warning? I don't believe so.

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe I'm going up against Skeet here in an answer, but...

I've had this in the past, where I had a DataAccess class that wrapped a bunch of Oracle Dll calls. Unfortunately MS obsoleted the Oracle classes, and it was throwing the warnings. I didn't like the idea of suppressing the obsolete warning across the board, since it would suppress other obsoletions in our own code, but we didn't have time to fix the issue (the class was used in quite a few places in different apps).

What I did, was use `#pragma` to disable the warning on that class:

```
#pragma warning disable 612, 618

public class MyWrapper
{
}

#pragma warning enable 612, 618
```

This, of course, works best if all the calls into the obsoleted classes are being made through a single point in your code, otherwise you would need to be setting the `#pragma` flag all over the place.

Comment: Yes, this is also what Resharper offers, but I have it in many places. I'm aware of the risk that we might introduce new obsolete classes without noticing it.

Comment: It must be `#pragma warning restore 612, 618`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma-warning